# Is it possible to use JIL with asp.net core rc2?

Tags: asp.net-core, jil

I'm trying to use Jil with asp.net core rc2, but there are no available package in nuget. Is it possible to start using jil + asp.net core rc2 today?

Comment: If this package supports dnxcore50 then yes.

Comment: @Pawel: ASP.NET Core is independent from .NET Core. It can also run against the full .NET Framework, so if the library supports .NET 4.5 or higher it can be used. Just not with .NET Core ;)

Comment: @Tseng - You are right - I did not read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jil 2.15.0 supports .Net core. (netstandard1.6).

Check this nuget link
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jil/2.15.0